# How to display only one formArray object?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am currently building a reactive form group where a user can enter ingredients. Initially the user can enter one ingredient(name, weight, metric unit) and as they save the ingredient,
a new input field appears where they can add another ingredient. This works well technically but I want to display the ingredients outside of the input fields and if a user clicks on the ingredient row being displayed, they can then edit it.

[image]

This is a mock up I made and the text in green is the placeholders for the input fields of the form array.

Here is how I am displaying the formArray:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="ingredients">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls; let i = index">
  <div class="ingredient-container" [formArrayName]="i">
   <div class="ingredient-row">
    <input
      class="input ingredient-text"
      formControlName="name"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Name"
    />
    <div class="ingredient-row">
      <input
        formControlName="weight"
        type="text"
        class="input ingredient-text"
        placeholder="Weight"
      />
      <input
        class="input ingredient-text"
        formControlName="metricUnit"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Metric Unit"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how it currently looks [image]

I know that the *ngFor is iterating over all the current ingredients which are being stored in the FormArray which is why it is displaying twice. I want to use a form array because I want to keep all the validation I've done but it seems like this is becoming an impossible task. Is there a feasible way to do this ?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You simple need take account that that your FormArray is a FormArray of FormGroups, so just create a function

```
indexSelected:number=-1
getGroup(index:number)
{
   return this.ingredients.at(index) as FormGroup
}
```

And use

```
<form *ngIf="indexSelected!=-1" [formGroup]="getGroup(indexSelected)">
...
</form>
```

You need "play" with the variable indexSelected -see that get the values from 0 to your-formArray.controls.length-1 -

NOTE: See that when you use

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls; let i = index">
    <!..see that you has a type error is formGroupName, not formArrayName-->
  <div class="ingredient-container" [formGroupName]="i">
      ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

is "like" you use

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls; let i = index">
  <div class="ingredient-container" [formGroup]="ingredients.at(i) as FormGroup">
      ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```